# Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $3$ such that $a_{ij} \in \{1, 0, -1\}$. Find the minimum of $\det A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, discrete-optimization

In this problem, i'm thinking of divide this into 2 cases, which are 'the matrix is LI' and 'the matrix is not LI'. If the matrix is not LI, then we have its determinant is zero, so i only consider the second case.

So im thinking that, with a diagonal matrix of order 3 such as below:

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

With only 2 types of elementary row operation are:

- Multiply a row by -1 or 1.
- Add 1 time or -1 time a row to another.

I can generate any matrix of order 3 that satisfy given requirements. With the determinant of the new matrix is either 1 or -1 time the diagonal matrix. With that i conclude that its determinant will have the minimum of -1. But this just feel so wrong.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: The $2 \times 2$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ has determinant $-2$, so you can do a little bit better than determinant $-1$ with a $3 \times 3$ matrix. Try experimenting!

Comment: As it turns out, the maximum for matrices of order $n$ are given by [this OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A003433).

Comment: @BenGrossmann Isn't that for binary matrices?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo As the title of the sequence says, it's for $\pm 1$ matrices. As the comments on [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A003432) note, the maximum (and hence minimum) for $\pm 1$ matrices is the same as the maximum for $(-1,0,1)$ matrices.

Comment: You can write this as minimizing a cubic polynomial subject to $3^2$ cubic equality constraints.

Answer (score 1):

After an exhaustive search, it seems that the minimal possible determinant is $-4$. One matrix for which this minimum is attained is
$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} -1 & -1 & -1\\ -1 & -1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 & -1 \end{array}\right).
$$
Here is the Matlab code with which I arrived at this answer.

```
n = 3;

m = 0;
A_m = zeros(n);

for i = 0:3^(n^2)-1
    numstr = dec2base(i,3,n^2);
    A = zeros(n);
    for j = 0:n-1
        for k = 0:n-1
            A(j+1,k+1) = str2double(numstr(1 + 3*j + k));
        end
    end
    A = A-1;
    d = det(A);
    if d < m
        A_m = A;
        m = d;
    end
end

disp('minimal determinant:')
m
disp('minimizing matrix:')
A_m
```

Comment: From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1058129) on a problem on the determinants of $\pm 1$ matrices (more generally, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2101303)) together with the [Hadamard problem on maximal determinants](http://oeis.org/A003432), we can figure this out in general for $n \times n$ matrices.

Comment: @prets It seems to me that you are assuming that minimizing the determinant for $\{\pm 1\}$ entries is equivalent to minimizing the determinant for $\{-1,0,1\}$ entries. That is, allowing zero entries does not allow for a lower determinant when looking for the minimal determinant among $\{\pm 1\}$ matrices, which is equivalent to the Hadamard problem. As the [comments on the sequence you linked](http://oeis.org/A003432) put it, you assume that we have $g(n) = h(n)$. So you are right, but the additional non-trivial fact is needed.